# Tomcat web.xml MIME mapping not working for .js.map file

Tags: xml, tomcat

Upon loading a page, I get the following lines in the log:

```
Mar 29, 2017 1:39:52 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl getMimeType
WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file jsxc.min.js.map.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
```

To accomplish this, I added

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js.map</extension>
    <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

to the `web.xml` file.  However, I am still getting the error. Why does it not accept the `.js.map` extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is returned because of the way the Tomcat servlet looks up the MIME by extension, namely:

(file: `java/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationContext.java`)

```
 // ...
 public String getMimeType(String file) {
    if (file == null)
        return (null);
    int period = file.lastIndexOf('.'); // <<<<<<<<<<<
    if (period < 0)
        return (null);
    String extension = file.substring(period + 1);
    if (extension.length() < 1)
        return (null);
    return (context.findMimeMapping(extension));
 }
 //...
```

On the marked position, only the last bit of the file extension (`.map`) is preserved, and that will be what is looked up.